# How can we see through the matter like glass

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

We have some categories of substances like transparent, opaque, translucent. My question is when it comes to transparent objects like glass which is solid, how can we see through it. Since matter is made up of atoms which contains electrons, protons, neutrons, etc, is it like are we seeing through them. If yes are these particles like electrons are see through particles. Does the same apply for water(does oxygen atoms and hydrogen atoms can be see-through) and atmosphere(which is combination of lot of gases which contain different particles). Ideally they should obstruct the path like the opaque objects do right? I have seen other questions but could not get proper understanding and those haven't answered my question.